# Do you need multiple start blocks rather than just multiple wires from one start block?

Tags: ev3

Using the Chromebook app I cannot have multiple "wires" from the start block to multiple sections of code blocks.  I have to use a start block for each section.  When I try to drag a wire it only moves the view.  Solutions?

Comment: It sounds like you already have the solution of using multiple start blocks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there doesn't seem to be anything to solve here, it sounds like a solution has already been found.

Comment: You could edit the question and then answer it. But I think Kenneth has moved away from Bricks.SE.

Comment: @Aziraphale Nah, editing out the OP's solution and posting it as an answer looks like a greedy way of grabbing some rep with little effort, and my answer would be too small anyway. [I already learned my lesson from that.](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/community-stance-on-solliciting-for-reputation?cb=1)

Comment: @mindstormsboi No, I was addressing Kenneth. Maybe he returns when he sees the reaction to his post.